# Why does text begin with #_ in HTML coding?

Tags: php

This question is probably for the PHP coders out there. I was looking at the code of the website I'm using and I came across something like this

```
<a href="{$config.root_url}/page.php">#_TEXTHERE#</a>
```

What is with the #_ text? How come it doesn't appear in the HTML webpage when loading? I don't see it declared anywhere?!?!

Thank you!

EDIT: 40 minutes later, after finished a bowl of ramen, I figured it out. If anyone wants to knows why the weird code, I have a weird explanation in my next post.

Comment: Please show the full code including the context this shows up in.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in the code the "#_TEXTHERE#" is replaced dynamically.

Comment: some templateing engine perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

The site is probably using a template engine or other system to replace that text. Probably for localization.

Comment: I am just too slow. Just what I was about to type ;-). Anyway. TEXTTHERE sucks as a label. Very non-descriptive. Maybe it is an incomplete script and the author wanted to place this as something like a "to do"-marker

Comment: yea basically without more details about the project, all answers are educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a template HTML file you are looking at. When the PHP script is called, #_TEXTHERE# will be replaced by whatever is appropriate at the time. Some example code would be,

```
$replacements['#_TEXTHERE#'] = "Click this link to go here";
return $this->renderTemplate($replacements);
```

$replacements is an associative array that contains all the replacements for the HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone, thank you for your QUICK replies. I think this is a very good community =).

And I understand the what it means now thanks to your explanations.

Yes, you all guessed it right. This code is NOT found anywhere. It was originally something like

```
<a href="{$config.root_url}/home.php">#_TP_Home_#</a>
```

I edited it thinking you all would reply with like "oh texthere is usually replaced with... under (whatever) situation." But that's not the case here. I learned to put more context next time. I'm a newbie php coder, sorry for the trouble.