# Explain the strange code html

Tags: html

I want to do a change in my site web (*html+css+php*)

I have this code html:

```
<h4>#_live_support#</h4>
```

In your opinion, what is the result of code??

No!No! result is not:

```
#_live_support#
```

a result CODE is Name Only:

```
Direct support
```

I want to explain this code please**

Photo caption

[code html]
http://goo.gl/vZQNXD

[Result]
http://goo.gl/4OaIvB

Comment: Refer to the following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911146/why-does-text-begin-with-in-html-coding

Answer (score 0):

This is a template HTML file you are looking at. When the PHP script is called, #_LIVE_SUPPORT# will be dynamically replaced by whatever is appropriate at the time.